# Retrieving records where sum of same columns with some condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, `table1` and `table2`, with same structure. The columns are `R`, `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`; `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` are `INT`s and `R` is `VARCHAR`.

I need all `R`s where sum of `a` in `table1` and `table2` is less than 40 and same for `b`, `c` and `d`.

The Statement that I executed is:

```
SELECT table1.R FROM table1,table2 where
table1.a + table2.a <40 or
table1.b + table2.b <40 or 
table1.c + table2.c <40 or 
table1.d + table2.d <40;
```

But it is giving unexpected results. The number of rows returned are far grater than the sum of number of records of two tables.

```
    table1                   table2
R   a   b   c   d            R      a     b    c    d
i1 45  28  29  22           i1      8   20   13    8
i2 28  28  29  30           i2      12   12  16     20 
i2 28  28  10  30           i2      12   12  16     20 
i2 28  5  29  30            i2      12   12  16     20 
i2 28  28  10  30           i2      12   12  16     20 
i2 28  28  29  30           i2      15   15  10     12 
i2 10  12  15  20           i2      8     3  6      12 

expected results 
i1

because table1.d+table2.d <40 for R = i1
```

Comment: You have no joining condition between the two tables. What relates them?  Values for `R`?

Comment: You're probably getting a cross product.  You need to add one or more join conditions; the "JOIN" syntax is clearer for this kind of thing -- `SELECT a.R from table1 as a INNER JOIN table2 as b ON a.id = b.id WHERE ...`.

Comment: sorry i wrote table.a instead of table1.a and table2.a. sorry for that  I'm editing it now.

Answer (score 1):

It's not totally clear, but what you probably want is:

```
SELECT table1.R FROM table1,table2 where
table1.R = table2.R and
(table1.a + table2.a <40 or
 table1.b + table2.b <40 or 
 table1.c + table2.c <40 or 
 table1.d + table2.d <40);
```

See this [FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a9c8/1)

Comment: this query is producing 0 - 29 (32,585,573 total, Query took 0.0004 sec) where I have table1 with 7000 records and table2 with 7000 records.

Comment: I don't know what that means. Is it producing the correct results?

Comment: Can you post some sample data and the expected results?

Comment: I posted example data and expected results in my question edit.

Comment: I made changes to sample data. so that will be more realistic.

Comment: Since the R column is not unique, the query joins each pair of rows with R=i2. This gets lots of matches because when each of them is joined with the last two rows of Table2, the condition is satisfied. You can change the query to `SELECT DISTINCT table1.R` if you want to suppress the duplicates.